# 'ClassName' and 'ClassInstance' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arm, embedded, atmelstudio, samd21

I am attempting to program an *Atmel SAM D21* microcontroller using C++ in *Atmel Studio*. I'm trying to create periodic hardware interrupts using one of the on-chip timers.

I created `Timer4` class to set up the timer from `main.cpp`. I tried to create a `Timer4` instance called `MyTimer4` in the main function, but it says

```
'Timer4' was not declared in this scope 
'MyTimer4' was not declared in this scope
```

I've seen many similar discussions pointing to incorrect/circular `#include`s. But, I don't seem to see the same problem on my own. Any ideas?

---

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "timerSAMD21.h"
#include "sam.h"

void SampleADC(void)
{

}

int main(void)
{
    SystemInit();

    Timer4 MyTimer4;

    MyTimer4.setRate(1000);
    MyTimer4.onEvent(SampleADC);
    MyTimer4.start;
}
```

---

**timerSAMD21.h**

```
#ifdef TIMERSAMD21_H
#define TIMERSAMD21_H

#include "tc.h"
#include "tc4.h"
#include "gclk.h"

typedef void (*voidFuncPtr)(void);

class Timer4
{

public:

    Timer4() {};
    void setRate(int frequency);
    void start(void);
    void end(void);
    void onEvent(voidFuncPtr funcOnEvent); 

private:

    void configure(int frequency);
    void enable(void);
    void disable(void);
    void reset(void);
};

#endif
```

---

**timerSAMD21.cpp**

```
#include "timerSAMD21.h"

voidFuncPtr callback = NULL;

void Timer4::setRate(int frequency) {
    configure(frequency);
}

void Timer4::start(void) {
    enable();
}

void Timer4::end(void) {
    disable();
    reset();
}

void Timer4::configure(int frequency) {
    //Configuration code here. Removed for Stack Overflow.
}

void Timer4::enable(void){
    REG_TC4_CTRLA |= TC_CTRLA_ENABLE;  //Enable timer
    while (TC4->COUNT8.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);
}

void Timer4::disable(void) {
    REG_TC4_CTRLA &= ~TC_CTRLA_ENABLE;
    while (TC4->COUNT8.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);  
}

void Timer4::reset(void) {
    REG_TC4_CTRLA = TC_CTRLA_SWRST;
    while (TC4->COUNT8.STATUS.bit.SYNCBUSY);
    while (TC4->COUNT8.CTRLA.bit.SWRST);

}

void Timer4::onEvent(voidFuncPtr funcOnEvent){
    callback = funcOnEvent;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void IRQHandlerTimer4(void) {
    if (callback != NULL) 
    {
        callback();
    }

    REG_TC4_INTFLAG = TC_INTFLAG_MC0;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: `#ifdef TIMERSAMD21_H` shoud be `#infdef TIMERSAMD21_H`.  Notice the extra n in `#ifndef` (for if not defined).

Comment: @MilesBudnek That looks like the/an answer. Would you like to make one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Note: Making an answer in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. Miles seems to have decided not to answer and I do not consider the problem a typo.)*

The way you attempt to prevent the reinclusion of your header is causing it to only make the content of the header visible if the guard-macro happens to be defined already, which it of course never is.

In order to fix this, change the

```
#ifdef TIMERSAMD21_H
#define TIMERSAMD21_H
```

into

```
#ifndef TIMERSAMD21_H
#define TIMERSAMD21_H
```

This will first keep the header content visible the first time it is included.
It will then define the guard macro, which will prevent the header content from being compiled a second time in the same translation unit, i.e. code file.

Comment: Wow thanks. That's something that would have taken me many hours to finally realize (as a novice programmer). Thank you for your explanation of what I inadvertently did too.

Comment: I was not aware. Brand new to Stack Overflow (I spend lots of time on traditional PHP forums), so there are definitely some etiquette things that aren't readily apparent to me. I have not yet verified the solution as I am not home at the moment, but upon checking, I will be sure to accept the answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: That is exactly the correct way to handle this. Have fun.

Comment: It compiled...after adding about 5 missing header files that I thought Atmel Studio would add automatically. Guess not. Thanks for the help. Your solution did indeed solve the particular problem I asked about.